# ggplot2 facet_wrap- histogram is plotting data incorrectly

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have a very large dataset and am trying to plot it in histograms using facet_wrap in ggplot2; after checking the raw data against the plot that ggplot2 has created, I have realised that although the plot seems to have the correct amount of data points, they do not correspond to the number of data points that should be in each bin, according to my data set- to verify this, I made a histogram of this plot in excel and it does look different. 
I don't know what I am doing wrong, I have tried lots of different code for the axis and different binwidths.

Here is the code

```
p1 <-ggplot(imp, aes(aindex)) + geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.1, color=("black"), fill = "transparent"  ) + 
  facet_wrap(~description, dir = "h", nrow = 3, scales = "fixed") +

  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(colour = "black", size = 0.05),
        axis.line.y = element_line(colour = "black", size= 0.05)) +

  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0),limits = c(0,10), breaks = seq(0,10,1)) +

  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"), 
        axis.text = element_text(colour = "black")) + xlab("Activity index impact") +

  ylab("Count") + theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 7), axis.text = element_text(size = 7))

p1
```

this code gives me this plot, and if we refer to the first plot,  entitled 01. SSN12, n = 16, compared to the plot on the right made in excel to see what the data should look like, with bindwidths of 0.1

does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

I have added my raw data in a shared dropbox folder

[link to imp data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lw5gxn4byqateei/imp.csv?dl=0)

[image: incorrect plot (ggplot2, left) and correct (excel, right)]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can reproduce Excel's binning behaviour by adding the additional parameter `center=0.05`, but I can't say if this is correct :

```
geom_histogram(center = 0.05, binwidth = 0.1, color = ("black"), fill = "transparent"  )
```